# Why don't the clothes follow the body movement properly when I change the character's pose?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

[image]

If I try to lower the arm even more it totally disrupts, do I make some mistakes in moving the parts around or is the problem somewhere else?

It gets even worse when I change the pose more

Comment: Probably the weights are wrong. The arm bone not affects the cloth as strong as the bone. You can correct it in Weight Paint mode or use weight transfer, or separate the covered body parts and hide them when there is a cloth on your character.

Comment: @FFeller sorry for the late reply but I discovered weight painting and it took me a while to understand what it was about. The problem is definitely there, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest adding a mask for the clothes. If you do not want to do this you could smooth the weights by going into weight painting mode > Weights > Smooth and expand the weights slightly.

Comment: hi Sven it's definitely about the weights, I tried what you said, but it did not make a big change, I will try to add a mask to the clothes but it's taking me a while to get a hang of how weights work. Thanks for the suggestion!